# How do I list Meteor users and only show their first email address?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, spacebars

I'm listing all the Meteor users in a template:

```
<template name="userList">
    <ul>
    {{#each users}}
        <li>
            {{_id}}<br>
            Emails:
                {{#each emails}}
                    {{address}},
                {{/each}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

Here's my helper:

```
Template.userList.helpers({
    users : function() {
        return Meteor.users.find({});
    }
});
```

This works, but since I'm not using usernames, I only want to list the first email address and not have to handle it with an {{#each}} in the template. Ideally, I'd have a value for users.primaryEmail, so I changed the helper to this:

```
Template.userList.helpers({
    users : function() {
        var rawUsers = Meteor.users.find({});
        var users = [];
        _.each(rawUsers, function(user) {
            user.primaryEmail = user.emails[0].address;
            users.push(user);
        })
        return users;
    }
});
```

...and updated my template code to output {{primaryEmail}}, but it doesn't seem to return any users at all now. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I needed to use .fetch() in order to get the results as an array & make users.emails[0] work:

```
var rawUsers = Meteor.users.find({}).fetch();
```